# How to access to glassfish's console by http not https?

Tags: http, https, glassfish-4

Glassfish4's console uses `https` to access, how could I use `http` instead of `https`?

I can find `'sec-admin-listener'` option in `config/domain.xml`, it uses `ssl` method.

I try to change this option, but failed.
Now I access to admin console is

```
https://ip:4848/
```

I want to use:

```
http://ip:4848/
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the admin console and execute the following command:

```
asadmin enable-secure-admin
```

Do not forget to restart the server to take the changes take effect.